# Can New Shepard launch from Texas and deliver payload (people) to Florida?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, commercial, new-shepard

Can New Shepard be used as transportation instead of a joy ride?

Is there any meaningful flight where you launch from Texas, and land somewhere nearby like California or Florida?

If it can't be done with it current design, are there small changes that can be made to do so? i.e. Go down from 6 - 4 people, or attach cold gas thrusters to 2nd stage instead of mass being wasted on the "joy ride" features inside the capsule.

If transportation is viable, how long is the flight?

Comment: NS series of flights reached ~100km, which translates to a deltaV of 1.5km/s, which further translates to a range of (less than) 450km.

Comment: [related](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/61045/40257), it seems unlikely based on that. [Also related](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51480/40257)