# How high can New Shepard fly?

Tags: altitude, blue-origin, new-shepard

If all the cargo onboard New Shepard were removed and the booster was not recovered, how high could it fly?

Comment: [Related](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53699/40257), I'll dust this code off and simulate this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same methods and data from [a previous answer of mine](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/53699/40257) about New Shepard I simulated a vertical launch of just the booster and got a maximum altitude of ~150 km:

[image: trajectory info]

(Personal Work)

Launching from the Cape it looks like this:

[image: 3D trajectory]

(Personal Work, blue = 3D trajectory, red = ground track)